# Postgres Group By preserving the previous order

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a query like:

```
SELECT foo_id, bar, timestamp, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp ASC)
FROM foo_table
WHERE (foo_id = '1' OR related_foo_id = '1')
AND foo_body -> 'type' = 'My_foo_type';
```

And I get this:

```
╔═════════╦══════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦
║ foo_id  ║    bar   ║  timestamp   ║  row_number  ║
╠═════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬
║  1      ║     1    ║      10      ║       1      ║
║  1      ║     1    ║      11      ║       2      ║
║  2      ║     1    ║      15      ║       3      ║
║  1      ║     2    ║      25      ║       4      ║
║  1      ║     2    ║      26      ║       5      ║
╚═════════╩══════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩
```

I want to group by 'foo_id' and 'bar' values to get something like this:

```
╔═════════╦══════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦
║ foo_id  ║    bar   ║  timestamp   ║  row_number  ║
╠═════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬
║  1      ║     1    ║      10      ║       1      ║
║  2      ║     1    ║      15      ║       2      ║
║  1      ║     2    ║      25      ║       3      ║
╚═════════╩══════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩
```

Grouping by foo_id and bar I have to get rid of timestamp column, but I need to order by it. I don't really care if I get the first row or the second one always that (foo_id, bar) is unique in the result.

I tried ordering and grouping the result:

```
SELECT A.foo_id, A.bar, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()
FROM (
  SELECT foo_id, bar FROM foo_table
  WHERE (foo_id = '1' OR related_foo_id = '1')
  AND foo_body -> 'type' = 'My_foo_type';
  ORDER BY timestamp ASC) A
GROUP BY foo_id, bar;
```

But it doesn't respect the order:

```
╔═════════╦══════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦
║ foo_id  ║    bar   ║  timestamp   ║  row_number  ║
╠═════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬
║  1      ║     1    ║      10      ║       1      ║
║  1      ║     2    ║      25      ║       2      ║
║  2      ║     1    ║      15      ║       3      ║
╚═════════╩══════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩
```

Also tried different joins following the answers in other questions, but I didn't find the right one. I always get the same result of the first select.

Is there a way to get what I want without impacting too much in the performance?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (foo_id, bar) foo_id, bar, timestamp, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp ASC)
FROM foo_table
WHERE (foo_id = 1 OR related_foo_id = 1) AND
      foo_body -> 'type' = 'My_foo_type'
ORDER BY foo_id, bar, timestamp asc;
```

This will return one row per `foo_id`/`bar` combination -- the one with the lowest timestamp.  This is based on the `order by` and `distinct on` clauses.

`DISTINCT ON` is a Postgres extension that is quite handy and can be the most efficient way to execute such a query.

Comment: Thank you so much. I already tried with distinct on but it seems I misunderstood its possibilities.

I had to add another select to your solution to get the right row number but the answer helped me a lot. Thanks